# Excel: enter value in cell depending on row index

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following problem that i can't solve.
I would like to enter in each cell of the first column (say from row 1 to row 20) 9_i, where i is the index of the row. For example, the first cell will contain 9_1, the second 9_2, the third 9_3, etc...
Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this is what you want.

in A1 `="9_"&ROW()`

Drag it down up to Cell A20.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!